# Plugins not showing in Admin

Tags: plugins, admin

I'm experiencing a problem where none of the plugins (2 captchas, and a random bookworm plugin) are showing up in my admin panel.

Folders are lowercase.

I've also checked permissions; folders are at 755. The corresponding file is at 644.

I have the Pixel & Tonic [Contact Form](https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/tree/v1) plus the [RetconHTML](https://github.com/mmikkel/RetconHTML-Craft) plugins currently in there, so I know I've successfully uploaded plugins before. Just not sure what's going on.

Thoughts?

**-edit-**

The two plugins I'm currently having problems with are [bookworm](https://github.com/mrnebbi/bookworm) and [recaptcha](https://github.com/aberkie/craft-recaptcha), not anything I've specifically developed.

Here's a screenshot of my plugins directory:
[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide links to the 2 captcha and bookworm plugins?  Or are these ones you've custom developed?

Comment: Weird... looks correct from the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

In the Settings area, I was expecting the plugin to show up in the Plugin section after uploading. Don't know why, but noticed last night that under the System section, there was a plugin option there. Once I went in there, and actually **installed** the plugin, it showed up under the Plugins section.

*sheesh*

Comment: Thanks man, your answer helped me! I installed my plugins via composer. So I had to go to the plugins page to install the plugins before they showed up.

Answer (score 6):

Probably the name of the folder isn't the plugin handle. Check inside the plugin's folder to see if the actual plugin folder is inside there. For instance:

```
forge@nys-production ~/nystudio107.com/craft/plugins (master) $ tree -L 1 craft-typogrify/
craft-typogrify/
├── readme.md
└── typogrify
```

In this case, when the plugin is downloaded or cloned, the name of the folder is `craft-typogrify` but the actual plugin folder is *inside* of this folder, and is named as a lowercase version of the plugin handle: `typogrify`.

This is what needs to be directly in the `craft/plugins` folder for Craft to see it.

Comment: I believe I have them correctly named. That seemed to be the most common reason for plugins not showing, so I checked that first. I've attached a screenshot to the original question - perhaps you'll see something I've missed.